# how to get correct NSDate from NSString without using dateFormatter

Tags: ios

because NSDateformatter cannot use custom calendar, so for a calendar like:

```
NSCalendar *ISO8601 = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierISO8601];
[ISO8601 setMinimumDaysInFirstWeek:7];
[ISO8601 setFirstWeekday:2];
```

If we need the weekofYear,

This calendar will translate 2015-04-26 16:00:00 as 2015-16th week.

So I will get a string as `2015-16th week`.

Then how can I convert string `2015-16th week` to a correct NSDate or DateComponents, so if you convert this new NSDate or dateComponents, it will not loose the correctness?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSDate *) dateByAddingWeeks:(NSInteger)dWeeks {

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
NSUInteger unitFlags = NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitTimeZone;
components = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:self];
components.day = components.day + 7 * dWeeks;
return [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];
}
```

Not sure.Are you looking for these kind of utility function?

Comment: nope, as your answer, I want input a NSString, and get a NSDate, without using NSDateFormatter. because I setup up a custom calendar: `firstWeekDay=2` and `MinimumDaysInFirstWeek=7`